# featurePlot R displaying NULL

Tags: r, scatter-plot, r-caret

I'm trying to make an overlayed density plot, but it keeps returning me NULL. I had the same problem with creating an ellipse plot, but after installing packages it's working. Any idea what I'm missing here?

```
transparentTheme(trans = .9)
featurePlot(x = data[, 1:4], 
            y = iris$diabetes,
            plot = "density", 
            scales = list(x = list(relation="free"), 
                          y = list(relation="free")),
            auto.key = list(columns = 3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the iris dataset then it should be:

```
library(caret)

featurePlot(x = iris[, 1:4], 
            y = iris$Species,
            plot = "density", 
            scales = list(x = list(relation="free"), 
                          y = list(relation="free")),
            auto.key = list(columns = 3))
```